# CGAL: 2D Constrained Delaunay Triangulation - Adding information to constraints

Tags: constraints, triangulation, cgal, delaunay

It is possible to attach informations (like ints) to points before adding them up to the triangulator object. I do this since I need on the one hand an int-flag that I use lateron to define my texture coordinates and on the other hand an index which I use so that I can create a indexed VBO.
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2_8cpp-example.html

But instead of points I only want to insert constraint-edges. If I insert both CGAL returns strange results since points have been fed into two times (once as point and once as point of a constrained edge).
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2constrained_8cpp-example.html

Is it possible to connect in the same way as with points information to "Constraints" so that I can only use this function `cdt.insert_constraint( Point(j,0), Point(j,6));` before I iterate over the resulting faces?

Lateron when I loop over the triangles I need some way to access the int-flags that I defined before. Like this but not on acutal points but the "ends" of a segment defined by the constraint edges:

```
for(CDT::Finite_faces_iterator fit = m_cdt.finite_faces_begin(); fit != m_cdt.finite_faces_end(); ++fit, ++k) {

    int j = k*3;
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {

        indices[j+i] = fit->vertex(i)->info().first;
    }
}
```

This question is part of another question I posted here: [Constrained (Delaunay) Triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062728/constrained-delaunay-triangulation).
Since it's a question of its own I posted it a second time independently.

Comment: Looks like I finally solved it! Following this instruction:
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/index.html#sectionextensiblekernel

Comment: Can you please post a self answer, with a description of your solution? I am not sure to anders and what you have described in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Author of question found the solution for himself, but did not post the answer. So, I will do it.

---

The answer located in those [examples](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/examples.html) and [explanation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/index.html#sectionextensiblekernel) on official website.

Will describe the case when you need just custom class for `Point`.

Take the source of [MyPointC2](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/Kernel_23_2MyPointC2_8h-example.html) and modify/add what you need.

```
#ifndef MY_POINTC2_H
#define MY_POINTC2_H
#include <CGAL/Origin.h>

class Point_i2 {
private:
  double vec[2];
  int ind;
public:
  Point_i2() : ind(0)
  {
    *vec = 0;
    *(vec+1) = 0;
  }
  Point_i2(const double x, const double y, int i = 0) : ind(i)
  {
    *vec = x;
    *(vec+1) = y;
  }
  const double& x() const  { return *vec; }
  const double& y() const { return *(vec+1); }
  double & x() { return *vec; }
  double& y() { return *(vec+1); }
  int index() const { return ind; }
  int& index() { return ind; }
  bool operator==(const Point_i2 &p) const
  {
    return ( *vec == *(p.vec) )  && ( *(vec+1) == *(p.vec + 1) && ( ind == p.ind) );
  }
  bool operator!=(const Point_i2 &p) const
  {
      return !(*this == p);
  }
};
#endif // MY_POINTC2_H
```

Then create new kernel:

```
#ifndef MYKERNEL_H
#define MYKERNEL_H
#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include "Point_i2.h"

// K_ is the new kernel, and K_Base is the old kernel
template < typename K_, typename K_Base >
class MyCartesian_base
  : public K_Base::template Base<K_>::Type
{
  typedef typename K_Base::template Base<K_>::Type   OldK;
public:
  typedef K_                                Kernel;
  typedef Point_i2                         Point_2;

  template < typename Kernel2 >
  struct Base { typedef MyCartesian_base<Kernel2, K_Base>  Type; };
};
template < typename FT_ >
struct MyKernel
  : public CGAL::Type_equality_wrapper<
                MyCartesian_base<MyKernel<FT_>, CGAL::Cartesian<FT_> >,
                MyKernel<FT_> >
{};
```

And now we can use our new kernel instead of default:

```
typedef MyKernel<double>                   MK;
typedef CGAL::Filtered_kernel_adaptor<MK>  K;
```