# Understand to which constrained edge a Steiner point belongs in constrained conforming triangulation CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

I followed the example reported here: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html (at paragraph "1.3 Example: Making a Triangulation Conforming Delaunay and Then Conforming Gabriel") to create a conforming constrained Delaunay triangulation using CGAL.
Making the triangulation conforming may introduce in the triangulation itself some Steiner vertexes that are not present among the original input vertexes. Is it possible to know to which original constrained edge a Steiner vertex belongs?
That is, when performing constrained triangulation, we can insert more than one CGAL::Polygon_2 into the triangulation as a constraint (it is done for example at this link from the CGAL manual: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html); so, in other words, I would like to know if I can understand to which of the original constrained edges (or, if not possible, to which polygon) a specific Steiner vertex belongs to, is it possible? and how could I achieve this?

Comment: Quick possibly completely wrong comment: You can input labeled points in triangulations in CGAL -- so perhaps you can label your inputs, pass those to CGAL, and then figure out which points are which that way? I remember doing that to obtain standard Delaunay triangulation as an abstract simplicial complex with integers for vertices.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. That's what I tried at beginning, following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186485/cgal-2d-constrained-delaunay-triangulation-adding-information-to-constraints. The problem is that the Steiner vertexes are introduced during the triangulation and when I retrieve the id, this is set to 0, so I have no info regarding the edge it belongs to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [`Constrained_triangulation_plus_2`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__triangulation__plus__2.html) with your current triangulation as base triangulation, you will have a notion of subconstraints that will give you access to vertices in the middle of original constraints. However, if you have intersection between your input constraints, the intersection vertices will also be reported as inside a constraint.

In [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2segment_soup_to_polylines_8cpp-example.html#_a2) you have an example of iteration over input constraints and look at vertices on the constraints.

Comment: Thank you, how could I create a CDTP (constrained_triangulation_plus_2) from my current CDT (constrained_triangulation_2)? Or should I create directly a CDTP?

Comment: You insert the constraints directly in CDTP, that way it knows what are original constraints.